# Cannot install Drupal 8 on Linux, php 5.6

Tags: symfony, drupal-8

I cannot install Drupal 8 on my linux server runing php5.6
My steps

1)Downloaded and extract drupal-8.2.1.tar.gz

2)rename drupal-8.2.1/ to drupal2

3) cd drupal2

4)composer update

when I go the web interface and try to install it gives so many 
like Symfony errors

User deprecated function: The Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::getScope method is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0. in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition->getScope() (line 603 of /home/tofa/www/drupal2/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Definition.php).

then it gives

```
Warning: stat(): stat failed for /home/username/www/drupal2/sites/default/files/css in Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\LocalStream->url_stat() (line 501 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/StreamWrapper/LocalStream.php).
Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\LocalStream->url_stat('public://css', 2)
is_dir('public://css') (Line: 1032)
file_scan_directory('public://css', '/.*/', Array) (Line: 184)
Drupal\Core\Asset\CssCollectionOptimizer->deleteAll() (Line: 202)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ThemeInstaller->install(Array, 1) (Line: 164)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ThemeHandler->install(Array) (Line: 1541)
install_profile_themes(Array) (Line: 660)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 538)
install_run_tasks(Array) (Line: 115)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
```

Not sure how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the official installation instructions located in the drupal folder (INSTALL.txt) or on drupal.org: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!INSTALL.txt/8.2.x

Answer (score 0):

Disabled `xdebug` and it fixed the issue :)

Answer (score -1):

I think Drupal 8 only works with PHP7 (and above)

Comment: It  supports PHP5.6

Comment: Drupal 8: PHP 5.5.9 or higher. See the full minimum recommendations for Drupal 7 & 8 at https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/overview